# How can I migrate DNS records from my service provider to amazon route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-sdk, amazon-route53, aws-php-sdk

I want to transfer my all my DNS records from my service provider to amazon route 53.

Currently i have almost 2500 records with my current DNS server.

My service provider have provided me a zone file from bind server.

Is there any script to add all these record in a single go to route 53 ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can load a zone file into AWS Route 53:

> If you're migrating from another DNS service provider, and if your
>   current DNS service provider lets you export your current DNS settings
>   to a zone file, you can quickly create all of the resource record sets
>   for an Amazon Route 53 hosted zone by importing a zone file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating-import.html

Comment: There is limit on number of records you are importing.Only 1000 records can be imported.
I have more than 2500 records.
Is there any script to do so ?

Comment: Here is a script: http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-Route-53/4495891528591897

Comment: Thanks !
I will check this script !

Answer (score 1):

I found one script.

Hope this will work

https://code.activestate.com/pypm/cli53/

https://github.com/barnybug/cli53/